# Как загрузить с HTTP и сохранить файл в нужный каталог?

Tags: python

Как загрузить с HTTP и сохранить файл в нужный каталог? Нужен код на Python аналогичный wget

Comment: Для этих целей можно использовать, например, urllib2. В документации имеются примеры использования этого модуля.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Использовал такой код:
    import urllib
    dlfile = urllib.URLopener()
    dlfile.retrieve(URL, filelocal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал такой код:

```
import urllib
dlfile = urllib.URLopener()
dlfile.retrieve(URL, filelocal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
open('/path/to/file.ext', 'w').write(
  urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/file/to/download.ext').read())
```

Answer (score 1):

[`urlretrieve(url, filename)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) позволяет скачать ссылку и сохранить её по указанному пути:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

> Нужен код на Python аналогичный wget

`wget` -- приложение с многочиcленными опциями, например, `wget` позволяет создать копию статических сайтов. Конкретные команды могут быть реализованы в Питоне, используя разные пакеты, например, [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org) позволяет гибко забирать с сайтов необходимую информацию. Если необходим общий http-клиент, то рекомендуется использовать [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org).